# mySQL Max function returns different type

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have table in mySQL (server version 8.0.12) with million records. Columns are:

```
Id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
Number tinyint(4) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
Date datetime DEFAULT NULL
TypeId int(11) DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
```

In the query below, less than sign change `Max(Number)` type from tinyint to bigint, while equals sign works fine (`Max(Number)` is tinyint).

```
SELECT tt.TypeId
     , MAX(tt.Number)
FROM (SELECT tt.Id
           , tt.Number
           , tt.Date
           , tt.TypeId
  FROM test_table tt) AS tt
WHERE tt.date BETWEEN '2020-06-09' AND '2020-06-10'
    AND tt.Id < 1052031
--  AND tt.Id = 1052030
GROUP BY tt.TypeId
ORDER BY tt.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

[image]

Without subquery everything also works fine(`Max(Number)` is tinyint):

```
SELECT tt.TypeId
     , MAX(tt.Number) Max
FROM test_table  AS tt
WHERE tt.date BETWEEN '2020-06-09' AND '2020-06-10'
 AND tt.Id < 1052031
--     AND tt.Id = 1052030
GROUP BY tt.TypeId
ORDER BY tt.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

[image]

Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: ? How do you know?

Comment: This isn't a MySQL CLI; it's some kind of GUI.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm using dbForge.

Comment: Datatype will be stored as TINYINT only when you use `=` by primary key (maybe when by unique expression too, but I doubt). In all other cases the most compatible type is used - for integer datatypes it is BIGINT (signed or not, depends on source column datatype).